# Inline Base64 images above 10KB not returned in MimeContent by EWS (Exchange Web Services)

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

As part of building a web-based email client where I'm adding a *Download email as .eml* feature, I'm trying to retrieve an email from Exchange via EWS and download it as an `.eml` file. I have this functionality working well, except for an issue relating to images.

In this email client, emails are constructed in the TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor, which allows image paste-from-clipboard; these images are base64 encoded, which I'll just call inline images here. When viewing in Outlook an email including an inline image sent from the above client, all is well - the image is present. However, when viewing the downloaded `.eml` file, only inline images that are less than 10KB are included; i.e. the `<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA[..]` tag is simply `<img>`.

I have assembled emails that include both a >10KB and a <10KB inline image, and on downloading, the >10KB image tag is stripped of the `src` attribute and the <10KB image tag is untouched. I would usually expect both or neither to be stripped, so I suspect there is some limit at play, but I've had no luck Googling for such a limit.

The code for retrieving the byte array is essentially the below:

```cs
var items = _ExchangeService.FindItems(folderId, filter, view);
_ExchangeService.LoadPropertiesForItems(items, BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
var emailMessage = items.First();
emailMessage.Load(new PropertySet(ItemSchema.MimeContent));

// Throwing only for debug purposes
if (System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(email.EmailMessage.MimeContent.Content).Contains("<img>"))
   throw new Exception("An image was stripped from the MimeContent");

return emailMessage.MimeContent.Content;
```

The >10KB inline images also appear to be stripped from `emailMessage.Body.Text`, so it seems less about `MimeContent` and more about some kind of policy/limit in EWS that I'm not aware of and can't find.

The version of EWS in use is v2017_07_11, 15.01.2507.034.

Comment: double check your ews message size and attachment size limits.

Comment: Exchange doesn't store messages as MIME so it will always be convert to and from its own Native store Methods. So don't expect that the MIME content would match exactly what you originally constructed, I would suggest you use a MAPI editor like Outlook Spy of MFCMapi and take a look at the native message in the Exchange store eg look at the attachments on the message etc you may find some conversion has happened.